# Delete/Insert UITableViewCell not in Editing mode

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, ios4

What's best solution to remove cell from tableview doing this not in editing mode. Like example switching to one view to another , update number of cells (after a previous delete or insert of cell) in `-viewWillAppear:` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSFetchedResultsController.  It will add/remove/update cells as it gets notifications when changes are made to NSManagedObjectContext that it was created with.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed (added/deleted) the values from the dataSource array then you can simply call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [beginUpdates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates)

Call this method if you want subsequent insertions, deletion, and selection operations (for example, cellForRowAtIndexPath: and indexPathsForVisibleRows) to be animated simultaneously.

You should not call reloadData within the group